# If statement in R using different parts of table

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in my table based on data from different parts of the table. My table is

```
SeqNr Length SerieNr
1     0      0
2     0      0
3     3      1
1     0      0
2     2      2
1     1      3
1     0      0
2     0      0
3     3      4
1
```

I have a table where each role describes an event. Sometimes these events are part of a sequence. I have determined the length of the sequence in the second column. Now I would like to add the third column `SerieNr` that adds a sequential number for each series.

In excel the formula for column `SerieNr` (assuming these columns are A,B,C) would be:

```
=if(b1=0;0;max($A$1:A1)+1)
```

It checks if column `Length` is non zero. If this is `true` then it takes the max number so far in column `SerieNr`and adds 1.

How can i achieve the same in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfN)[Length!=0, SerialNr2:= seq_len(.N)]
```

The above will fill `NA` values in "SerialNr2" for corresponding 0 values in "Length".  If needed, this can be changed to 0

```
dfN[is.na(SerialNr2), SerialNr2:= 0]
dfN 
#      SeqNr Length SerieNr SerialNr2
#1:     1      0       0         0
#2:     2      0       0         0
#3:     3      3       1         1
#4:     1      0       0         0
#5:     2      2       2         2
#6:     1      1       3         3
#7:     1      0       0         0
#8:     2      0       0         0
#9:     3      3       4         4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "SeqNr Length SerieNr
                 1     0      0
                 2     0      0
                 3     3      1
                 1     0      0
                 2     2      2
                 1     1      3
                 1     0      0
                 2     0      0
                 3     3      4", header = TRUE)

DF$SeqNr2 <- 0
#subset and create a sequence along the subset
DF[DF$Length != 0, "SeqNr2"] <- seq_along(DF[DF$Length != 0, "SeqNr2"])
#  SeqNr Length SerieNr SeqNr2
#1     1      0       0      0
#2     2      0       0      0
#3     3      3       1      1
#4     1      0       0      0
#5     2      2       2      2
#6     1      1       3      3
#7     1      0       0      0
#8     2      0       0      0
#9     3      3       4      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base `R` one-liner approach:

```
df$SerieNr = ifelse(df$Length, cumsum(df$Length!=0), 0)

#> df
#  SeqNr Length SerieNr
#1     1      0       0
#2     2      0       0
#3     3      3       1
#4     1      0       0
#5     2      2       2
#6     1      1       3
#7     1      0       0
#8     2      0       0
#9     3      3       4
```